# I'm using bootstrap. How can I put error message inside my modal using php?

Tags: php, html

PHP File

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $emailuid = $_POST['emailuid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd1'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='$emailuid' AND pwd='$pwd' OR 
    email='$emailuid' AND pwd='$pwd'";
    $result = $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if(!$row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "Your Username or Password does not match";
    }else{
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location: home.php");
    }

?>
```

Html File

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="form-group">
                <h1>Login</h1>
            </div>
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="login.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group input-group pb-modal-reglog-input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                    <input class="form-control" name="emailuid" placeholder="Email or Username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group pb-modal-reglog-input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd1" placeholder="password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox">
                            Remember me.
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary col-lg-12" type="submit" name="btn_submit">Login</button>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a href="#">Forgot password?</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Here's the code. Can someone please help me with this? Both codes are separate files, login.php and index.php now I want to display the error message inside my modal under the password input how will I do this? Thanks. I'm using bootstrap by the way and I'm still new to this together with php.

Comment: Be more descriptive please.

Comment: Use parameterized queries and hash your passwords.

Comment: It can't be done with PHP alone without an ugly outcome... use ajax instead.

Comment: Yeah, using just PHP you're whole page is going to have to reload every time you want to open (or close) that modal. Use JavaScript.

Comment: Oh shit.. forgot to thank you guys. It helped me a lot! Thanks @Toastrackenigma it solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the two files (php,html) submit the form to the same index.php then put condition statement to check if post request was made if it has then enter the checking block of your php code. Do the same checking in your html with inline php and if its post then check if it was sucessfull and display your message accordingly. 
Without ajax i think this is the only solution i can think of